# How to check if value doesn't exist in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have this php code:

```
<?php
  $A=['dog', 'cat', 'monkey'];
  $B=['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey'];

  foreach($A as $animal) {
    if(!in_array($animal, $B)) {
      echo "$animal doesn't exist<br>";
    }
  }
?>
```

But the if statement never executes. What I'm I doing wrong? What is the proper way to check if a value **doesn't** exist in array?

Comment: Dog, cat AND monkey are ALL in array `$B`, so of course the if loop gets never called. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $A=['dog', 'cat', 'monkey'];
  $B=['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey'];

  foreach($B as $animal) {
    if(!in_array($animal, $A)) {
      echo "$animal doesn't exist<br>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Output: `rat doesn't exist`

Answer (score 2):

With use of php `in_array()` and `ternary operator`.

```
$A=['dog', 'cat', 'monkey'];
$B=['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey'];
foreach($A as $animal) {
    $result[] = in_array($animal, $B) ? "$animal exist": "$animal does not exist";
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check exist or not like this

```
<?php
  $A=['dog', 'cat', 'monkey'];
  $B=['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey'];

  foreach($A as $animal) {
    if(in_array($animal, $B)) {
      echo "exist";
    }
    else{
        echo 'not exist';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to check which exist and which doesn't.

```
<?php
  $A=['dog', 'cat', 'monkey'];
  $B=['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey'];

  foreach($A as $animal) {
    if(in_array($animal, $B)) {
      echo "$animal exists in \$B<br/>";
    }
    else{
        echo "$animal does not exist in \$B<br/>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is true every time because all elements of array `A` exists in array `B`. Try adding a new element and then see.

```
<?php
    $A=['dog', 'cat', 'monkey', 'kite'];
    $B=['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey'];

    foreach($A as $animal) {
       if(!in_array($animal, $B)) {
         echo "$animal doesn't exist<br>";
       } else {
         echo "$animal exist<br>";
    }
?>
```

Think the logic first before implementing a program.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php    /*try this function,,
array_key_exists(array_key, array_name)*/

 $A=['dog', 'cat', 'monkey'];
 $B=['cat', 'rat', 'dog', 'monkey'];

foreach($A as $animal) {
if(array_key_exists($animal, $B)) {
  echo "$animal doesn't exist<br>";
  } else{echo"$animal doesnot exit<br>";}
```